# Unity3D - How to get an objects spawned when a client joined?

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple network game and I have a problem. Basilicaty, when any client joins the game a square is spawned (by NetworkManager component) and the client can control only that one square. My problem is: how do I get a gameObject with the square from server view? I mean I want to change a square's color to e.g blue, so every connected client sees that particular square as a blue square. Any ideas guys? (a gameobject with a square has NetworkIdentity component)

I tried that:

`var a = NetworkServer.connections[NetworkServer.connections.Count() - 1].clientOwnedObjects; GameObject go = NetworkServer.FindLocalObject(a.ElementAt(previousPositions.Length));`

but I got exception which says that GameObject go is a null

Comment: please post some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple variation like color you can probably do it with scripting, just a property on the object set by the server.
If you need something more complex, an entire asset bundle, try looking at these two options:

[WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html)

[UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html)